# svelte reactive value doesn't update on store change

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

Hi guys I have this code to check if an item is selected

```
$: checkbox = $chosenPackage.products.find(e => e.id == selectedProduct.product.id && e.name == selectedProduct.product.name)?.variants.some(e => e.id == v.id && e.name == v.name) || false
```

I `console.log` the result and it always returns undefined however when i run it in the console, (replacing all the stores with duplicated objects) it returns the right value

It was working before but I had to change the structure of the store and that's when it stopped working, the markup behaves as it's supposed to, (all the classes for `checkbox == true` are applied) but it's not reactive, meaning when I remove a variant from the array it doesn't remove the classes, and when I check the store I see the variant has been correctly removed,

When the components rerender everything looks good, but it's supposed to rerender automatically if `checkbox` changes and `checkbox` is supposed to change automatically if anything in the store changes but it doesn't

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Edit: I just realized that in another part it does get updated

Here is the code that updates the store in the part that doesn't work

```
$chosenPackage.products.find(e => e.id == selectedProduct.product.id && e.name == selectedProduct.product.name).variants = [v]
```

So I am basically overwriting the entire array with the new selected variant

Comment: Could you share more context / the surrounding code? Else it's hard to say what causes this.

Comment: @dummdidumm which part will help clarify?

Comment: Where and how is $chosenPackage updated?

Comment: I am adding some more information about that

Comment: Boy, that really hurts!  Er… what exactly is a “sore change”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a method invocation inside your update assignment (`find`). As soon as there's such a method invocation, Svelte does not compile that into a "update the store" statement anymore because it can't know what that method does and if it would be right to update the store. Therefore use the `update` method in this case

```js
chosenPackage.update(current => {
  current.products.find(e => e.id == selectedProduct.product.id && e.name == selectedProduct.product.name).variants = [v];
  return current;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, that will probably solve a lot of other problems i was having, So if I invoke a method, that method has to return the final result? because i have other places where I am invoking methods on arrays and objects and it does work

Comment: No this is only related to updating stores. Svelte will not trigger a store update when there's a method in the assignment chain because it doesn't know if the result of that method has anything to do with the store value / if it updates the store value. `$chosenPackage[0].a = true` would work for example, because these are static reads, so Svelte knows this will change the store value.